# Puppeteer waitForSelector is not working inside loop

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

My task is form submission with different data. So, I am using puppeteer and  for of loop.

Code example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const data = require('data.json') // ~30 products

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      defaultViewport: null,
    });

   const page2 = await browser.newPage();
   await page2.goTo('mywebsite', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'} )

    for (let product of data) {

      // Waiting for some selector, after that do something with it
      await page2.waitForSelector("#someSelector", { visible: true });
      await page2.type("#someSelector", product.someData);


         //
    //... A lot of code that similar to above is here

        //


      // Go back after all things done
      await page2.waitFor(2000);
      await page2.waitForSelector('[title="home"]', { visible: true });
      await page2.click('[title="home"]', { clickCount: 1 });


      counter++;

      console.log(
        `===========================================================================${counter}`
      );


    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
})();
```

The problem is that **this is works**, but *not always works*, for example, a loop can work 15 times, and then fall off or go through a full cycle without failing.

The error is always the same:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#someSelector" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

However, if I check the page, then everything is there, the elements are on the page, but puppeteer does not see them. How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution for this is a retry function:

```
const chalk = require("chalk");
const util = require("util");

const delay = util.promisify(setTimeout);

async function retry(fn, retryDelay = 200, numRetries = 5) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numRetries; i++) {
    try {
      return await fn();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(
        "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
      );

      console.log(chalk.yellow(err));
      if (i === numRetries - 1) throw err;
      await delay(retryDelay);
      retryDelay = retryDelay * 2;
    }
  }
}
```